# How to validate array values as part of a unique set of values in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a `days` table with `day`, `start_time`, `end_time` columns. I've set these 3 columns as a unique set of values in my migration `$table->unique(['start_time', 'end_time', 'day'])`.

Currently I'm validating them like this:

```
'day.*.day' => [
                'required',
            ],
'time.*.start_time' => [
                'required', 'different:time.*.end',
            ],
'time.*.end_time' => [
                'required', 'different:time.*.start',
            ]
```

But I also want to add `Rule::unique()` validation rule so each set of values are different from each other. I've done similar validation but not to an array value.

I've tried tinkering with it for hours, I did try to loop some stuff but unfortunately it doesn't work that way.

```
        foreach ($schedule->days as $day) {

            $time = request()->validate([
                "day" => [
                    'required',
                    Rule::unique('days')
                        ->where('day', request('day')[$day->id]['day'])
                        ->where('start_time', request('time')[$day->id]['start_time'])
                        ->where('end_time', request('time')[$day->id]['end_time'])
                ],
                // and so on ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Just modify a little part from this

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'data.ip' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('servers')->where(function ($query) use($ip,$hostname) {
            return $query->where('ip', $ip)
            ->where('hostname', $hostname);
        }),
    ],
],
```